# How to improve this LINQ query

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-entities

I'd appreciate any suggestions on improving this LINQ query. I am querying a list of all states which are : 1. published, 2. have any city which is published AND have any place which is published.

Entities, view-models, and relationships:

```
public class State {
    public long Id { get; set; }
    public bool Published { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public IList<City> Cities { get; set; }
}
public class StateModel {
    public long Id { get; set; }
    public bool Published { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<CityModel> Cities { get; set; }
}

public class City {
    public long Id { get; set; }
    public bool Published { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public State State { get; set; }
    public IList<Place> Places { get; set; }
}
public class CityModel {
    public long Id { get; set; }
    public bool Published { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int PlacesCount { get; set; }
}

public class Place {
    public long Id { get; set; }
    public bool Published { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public City City { get; set; }
    public RecordStatus Status { get; set; }
}
// also I have a view-model named PlaceModel just like the Place itself.

// RecordStatus is an enum, nothing special
```

And I'm querying states with this snippet:

**SEE UPDATE PLEASE!!! This snippet is expired.**

```
Func<Place, Boolean> placeSelector = 
    p => p.Published && p.Status != RecordStatus.Banned;

Func<City, Boolean> citySelector = 
    c => c.Published && c.Places.Any(placeSelector);

var linq = from state in _context.States.AsNoTracking()
           where state.Published
           where state.Cities.Any(citySelector)
           select new StateModel {
               Id = state.Id,
               Name = state.Name,
               Cities = state.Cities
                             .Where(citySelector)
                             .Select(city => new CityModel {
                                 Id = city.Id,
                                 Name = city.Name,
                                 PlacesCount = city.Places.Count(placeSelector)
                             })
           };
```

As you can see, I', querying on `state.Cities` 3 times: one with `Any()` with a predicate of `citySelector`, another one is a projection on `state.Cities` for per `state` with the predicate as before, and the last one just for counting all places in each city. I know that I can execute the predicate just one time at sql-server (not like my snippet which is executing 3 times), but I can't figure it out how? Any suggestion? Thanks in advance.

**UPDATE:**

There was a mistake (mine) that I used `Func<,>` instead of `Expression<Func<,>>` which push A's attention to a point which was not my Q's point. So I Edit the query:

```
var linq = from state in _context.States.AsNoTracking()
           where state.Published
           where state.Cities.Any(c => c.Published && c.Places
                                 .Any(p => p.Published && p.Status != RecordStatus.Banned)
                             )
           select new StateModel {
               Id = state.Id,
               Name = state.Name,
               Cities = state.Cities
                             .Where(c => c.Published && c.Places
                                 .Any(p => p.Published && p.Status != RecordStatus.Banned))
                             .Select(city => new CityModel {
                                 Id = city.Id,
                                 Name = city.Name,
                                 PlacesCount = city.Places
                                                   .Count(p => p.Published && p.Status != RecordStatus.Banned)
                             })
           };
```

I'm looking for some suggestions to improve this query please.

Comment: Are your selectors actually `Func<X, Boolean>`s like that?

Comment: @Rawling yes they are exactly what I wrote in Q. Have they any problems?

Comment: See my answer - I'm not 100% sure of it but give it a try.

Answer (score 2):

I think your use of `Func<X, Boolean>` is forcing LINQ to use the [`Enumerable` overload of e.g. `Any`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/vstudio/bb534972.aspx), which takes place in C#, rather than the [`Queryable` overload](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb534338.aspx), which can take place in SQL.

Try declaring your selectors as

```
Expression<Func<Place, Boolean>> placeSelector = 
    p => p.Published && p.Status != RecordStatus.Banned;

Expression<Func<City, Boolean>> citySelector = 
    c => c.Published && c.Places.Any(placeSelector);
```

which will require `using System.Linq.Expressions;`.

Comment: As far as I am aware the only way to switch the context of a LINQ query is to use `AsEnumerable`, I don't think an overloaded parameter would do that (I could well be wrong though).

Comment: @James `AsEnumerable` is the same principle. `IQueryable` has no `AsEnumerable` extension method, so `AnIQueryable.AsEnumerable()` calls `Enumerable.AsEnumerable(this IEnumerable)` which just returns the source `IQueryable` downcast as an `IEnumerable`. In the same way, `IQueryable` has no (e.g.) `Any(this IQueryable, Func)` extension method so it ends up calling `Enumerable.Any(this IEnumerable, Func)`. This again causes the source to be downcast to `IEnumerable`.

Comment: Interesting, so in this scenario would anything called after `Any` still be in memory or would it still be `IQueryable<T>`? It's almost like you would want `IQueryable<T>` to override those methods and throw a `NotImplementedException` or give some sort of hint that you should explictly switch the context via `AsEnumerable`. It would provide better readability and help understand what can be run at the server and what can't. Regardless, +1 because I reckon this is most likely the problem.

Comment: @James Actually I'm not so sure now. The `[IQueryable].Where(state => state.Cities.Any(citySelector))` call that OP's query syntax produces still returns an `IQueryable` even though the `citySelector` shouldn't be exectuable on the database. I can't tell whether it is magically executing on the database, whether it is executing locally and subsequent queries *are* happening in memory, or whether it'll throw an exception because it can't translate to the database.

Comment: @Rawling +1 for trying. See update please. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can use the `let` keyword. Like this:

```
var linq = from state in _context.States.AsNoTracking()
                let cities=state.Cities.Where(citySelector)
                where state.Published
                where cities.Any()
                select new StateModel {
                   Id = state.Id,
                   Name = state.Name,
                   Cities = cities.Select(city => new CityModel {
                                     Id = city.Id,
                                     Name = city.Name,
                                     PlacesCount = city.Places.Count(placeSelector)
                                 })
               };
```

Comment: +1 it seems a good improvement. thanks

Comment: I would be surprised if that makes any difference, it's still going to evaluate once for `Any` and again for `Select`.

Answer (score 1):

`Func<T1, T2, ...>` is a piece of compiled code which LINQ-to-Entities/LINQ-to-SQL can't covert back into SQL. Writing it as such forces SQL to run a potentially expensive query and then run the results of it back through your compiled .NET `Func<>` code.

`Expression<Func<T1, T2, ...>>` is uncompiled code which LINQ-to-Entities/LINQ-to-SQL can convert back into SQL code and run your whole query on SQL, rather than run bits and pieces of it in SQL, other bits and pieces in .NET and make a mess of the whole thing.

As a general rule, you should declare your predicates for LINQ as `Expression<Func<T1, T2, ...>>` **all the time** and call `.Compile()` on them to covert them back to `Func<T1, T2, ...>` only when needed.

Comment: +1 for trying. See update please. Thanks.

Comment: @Javad_Amiry what type of improvement are you looking for? better memory usage or faster execution speed? Because it's possible that those two might be mutually exclusive, depending on your database design. Also, depending on how much data is in your tables, performance can be greatly affected by the difference between using `Expression` and `Func`.

Comment: Well for an example, in the query, I'm querying `Cities` 3 times. I'm looking for a way to combine them in 1 query.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to avoid repetitive queries, you could go bottom-up instead of top-down which you are doing now. For example:

```
var places = _context.Places.Where(x => x.Published && x.Status != RecordStatus.Banned)
                            .GroupBy(x => x.City.Id)
                            .Select(x => new
                             {
                                 CityId = x.Key,
                                 Count = x.Count()
                             })
                             .ToList(); // db query

var cityIds = places.Select(y => y.CityId).ToList(); //in memory

var cityModels = _context.Cities.Where(x => x.Published && cityIds.Contains(x.Id))
                                .Select(x => new CityModel
                                {
                                    Id = x.Id,
                                    Name = x.Name,
                                    Published = x.Published,
                                    StateId = x.State.Id, // added this to your model
                                    PlacesCount = 0
                                })
                                .ToList(); // db query

cityModels.ForEach(x => x.PlacesCount = places.FirstOrDefault(y => y.CityId == x.Id).Count); //in memory

var stateIds = cityModels.Select(x => x.StateId).Distinct().ToList(); //in memory

var stateModels = _context.States.Where(x => x.Published && stateIds.Contains(x.Id))
                                 .Select(x => new StateModel
                                 {
                                     Id = x.Id,
                                     Name = x.Name
                                 }).ToList(); // db query

stateModels.ForEach(x => x.Cities = cityModels.Where(y => y.StateId == x.Id)); //in memory
```

Comment: Thanks but there is 3 db queries

Comment: This is the only real alternative. 

You either make one huge select with lots of `JOIN`s and `APPLY`s  (accessing a foreign key property in LINQ = `JOIN`; let = `APPLY`) which can be very slow, or you break it down into a few smaller queries which are much faster because they avoid `JOIN`s and filter by the identity column, which is very fast.

Comment: @Javad_Amiry I'm assuming you're concerned about performance. One query with lots of redundant `JOIN`s and `APPLY`s can be orders of magnitude slower than 3 separate queries which avoid expensive `JOIN`s and `APPLY`s, especially when the data set gets bigger.